# iOS app ScrollView not working when segue changed from Show (Push) to Present Modally

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I have a tableviewcell, on clicking which the app navigates to a new storyboard. The storyboard has a scrollView to display images and a page control at the bottom. The segue to this storyboard was configured as a Show (Push). Now, I am trying to switch the segue kind to Present Modally. In the app now when I touch the tableviewcell, the modal pops up as expected (cover vertical), but none of the images are displayed. A blank screen gets displayed with the page control at the bottom. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Without more information, we can only guess. Modal view controllers are separate in the view hierarchy. Maybe your presented view controller is dependant on a navigation/tabbar controller?

Comment: Yes it does have a navigation controller. Could that be causing this?

Comment: Possibly - but I can't tell without seeing either symptoms or code. Just to clarify - did you already wrap the presented view controller inside a navigation controller? If not, try that and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Yeah, that is already done.